# Xaml based sample template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I have been googling out for this but can not find a single link for this.
What I want is  ( as we have many HTML template designs available on net ) some design to start with my travel management app.
Surprisingly even I found it win phone also

http://wp7designtemplates.codeplex.com/documentation

I want similar kind of thing for desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

You can get links to ready made XAML templates [here](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/02/readymade-xaml-styles-and-templates.html)

Comment: Hey one of the link is for theme and m already consuming it and the first one provides xamal but its not as expected